# How to merge dataframes to every row in a second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The array of data will come from other source, so in this example I have declared them as array and with minimal data. But the combinations of the entries in lists will be a lot more over million combinations. It's like the length of ar1 * arr2 * arr3 etc.

```
arr1 = [1, 2]
arr2 = [10, 20]
arr3 = [0.1, 0.2]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr1, columns=["col1"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2, columns=["col2"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(arr3, columns=["col3"])
```

Final result of the new DataFrame should be all of posible combinations of the given arrays:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    10   0.1
1    10   0.2
1    20   0.1
1    20   0.2
2    10   0.1
2    10   0.2
2    20   0.1
2    20   0.2
```

Answer (score 3):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html effectively does what you want.  Simple to then change to a dataframe

```
arr1 = [1, 2]
arr2 = [10, 20]
arr3 = [0.1, 0.2]

pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([arr1, arr2, arr3], names=["col1","col2","col3"])).reset_index()
```

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works really great and fast!

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 116699440 entries, 0 to 116699439

0:00:19.764027

Comment: And is it also posible to apply a function to every row that is created and put the result in a DataFrame into a column eg. df["extra"] = function(x) than returns a pd.DataFrame?

This is because every row contains different values as you can see and with those values a calculation has to run which have calculated results in a table.

Comment: you mean `apply(lambda r: r.sum(), axis=1)`?  you can put result into the same data frame or a new dataframe.   Not really sure why you'd want another dataframe rather than just another column...

Comment: One of the columns in the main DF has a value eg. 7. That value means that I have to make 7 calculation with other parameters. The caculation will result in 7 rows with several columns with outcome.
So the main DF contains parameters and on every row in need an extra columns which contains a table with results based on the parameters. And within that table I need to search/compare data. Hope this make some clear.

Comment: `bo     so   tp  sopd  msot  soss  sovs    extra
0    10.0   10.0  1.0   1.0   7.0   1.0   1.0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1    10.0   10.0  1.0   1.0   7.0   1.0   1.1  [0, 1.1, 2.6, 3.2, 4.2, 5.7, 6.4, 7.1]`

Comment: sounds like the function returns a list.  that's fine,  you can then do an `explode()` on it

Answer (score 2):

### `functools.reduce` and `pd.merge`

Kind of slow.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

reduce(
    pd.merge,
    [d.assign(dummy=1)
     for d in [df1, df2, df3]
    ]).drop('dummy', axis=1)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   0.1
1     1    10   0.2
2     1    20   0.1
3     1    20   0.2
4     2    10   0.1
5     2    10   0.2
6     2    20   0.1
7     2    20   0.2
```

---

### `itertools.product` and `pd.DataFrame.itertuples`

Definitely faster

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

def tupify(d): return d.itertuples(index=False, name=None)
def sumtup(t): return sum(t, start=())

pd.DataFrame(
    list(map(sumtup, product(*map(tupify, [df1, df2, df3])))),
    columns = sum(map(list, [df1, df2, df3]), start=[])
)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   0.1
1     1    10   0.2
2     1    20   0.1
3     1    20   0.2
4     2    10   0.1
5     2    10   0.2
6     2    20   0.1
7     2    20   0.2
```

Comment: Dang... I sure miss your level of insight on here.  +1  "tupify"  SMDH

Answer (score 0):

[expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) is a fast implementation of cartesian product and uses `np.meshgrid` under the hood.

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

# expand_grid requires a dictionary:

others = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2, "df3": df3}

jn.expand_grid(others = others).droplevel(1,1)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   0.1
1     1    10   0.2
2     1    20   0.1
3     1    20   0.2
4     2    10   0.1
5     2    10   0.2
6     2    20   0.1
7     2    20   0.2
```

[expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) can also be extended to cartesian product of dataframe and series, and even non pandas objects. It's end product though is a dataframe.